# Redshift UNLOAD command with extension parameter throws syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am attempting to unload data from Redshift using the `extension` parameter to specify a CSV file extension. The CSV extension is useful to allow data files to be opened e.g. in spreadsheet software.

The command I run is:

```sql
unload ('select * from public.mytable') 
to 's3://mydomain/fZyd6EYPK5c/data_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/my-role' 
parallel off 
format csv 
extension '.csv.gz' 
gzip 
allowoverwrite;
```

This command throws an error message:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "extension"
```

It appears that the `extension` option is not recognized. I believe I have followed the official documentation and examples:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html

```sql
select version();

PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.44903
```

I am testing the query from a Java application and from DBeaver.

Do I have a syntax error in my query? Could this be a Redshift bug? Asked on AWS [forum](https://repost.aws/questions/QUjKAmoPlVTgiTk8wXfPEOeg/redshift-unload-command-with-extension-parameter-throws-syntax-error). Replies appreciated.

Comment: Does the unload statement run if you remove the extension option?  Narrowing it down to the exact option will help. Also be aware that specifying "parallel off" doesn't guarantee that a single file will be made. If the file is over 5GB (default size limit) multiple files will be created. This is common incorrect assumption and leads to future issues.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Yes the unload statement works when I remove the "extension" parameter and value. It also runs with and without "parallel off". The generated file is small at around 1 MB.

Comment: Good. I haven't used this combo of options before but have a few ideas to try. First make sure there are no non-printing or non-ascii characters in your string.  Next check to see if there is an interaction between options. One that may is the CSV option as there could be an undocumented implied extension that is conflicting. Lastly see if the keyword "format" is confusing the parser as I haven't used this keyword in a long time. Just "CSV".

Comment: Also note the file size limit for future reference if there is any chance of file size growth. It is surprising how fast things grow with time.

Comment: Thanks for your support Bill. I can confirm there are no non-ascii characters in the query string, and the query runs fine without the extension parameter. I get the same error with and without the "format csv" parameter and value. Excluding "." from the extension value makes no difference. The data file to load is static and small. I am leaning towards Redshift being broken here. Perhaps the "extension" keyword is not recognized or confused with Postgres extensions.

Comment: Try moving the extention line below gzip. That would be the only option idea left. If that does not work, maybe raise a ticket with the support.

Comment: Tried moving extension below gzip without success. Created a post on the AWS forum.

Comment: I think that is the right move.  You are getting a syntax error on simple text value insertion functionality (add this text to the end of the file name).  Please post any resolution here.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the extension feature was not rolled out to my Redshift cluster yet. Asked on the AWS forum and the parameter is available after version 1.0.45698.

> Extension parameter is a feature released recently and it's available after version 1.0.45698. You are seeing this error since your cluster version 1.0.44903 is lower than this. Please wait until next maintenance window or try creating a new cluster/workgroup to get the updated version. Cluster versions and released features are documented in following [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/cluster-versions.html#cluster-version-173).